# Powershell - Skip folder if it doesn't exist

Tags: powershell, directory, skip

I would like to run a PowerShell script by right-clicking a .PS1 file -> Run with PowerShell. The issue is that the `$srcRoot` includes three different parent directories, which one, some, or none may exist of `'C:\parentfolder5.5\web\','C:\parentfolder7.0\web\', and/or 'C:\parentfolder8.0\web\'`. However, running the script directly in a PowerShell terminal seems to work for the parent folders that do exist even though there are errors that pop up for the parent folders that do not exist.

The goal would be to continue running the script based on the parent directories that do exist, which currently it looks like the .PS1 file stops after looking at the first item in the `$srcRoot` list. Below is the code being worked on:

```
$filterLists = '*overview*', '*summary*', '*home*', '*floor*', '*flr*', '*level*', '*lvl*', '*roof*', '*basement*', '*first*', '*second*', '*third*', '*fourth*'

$srcRoot = 'C:\parentfolder5.5\web\','C:\parentfolder7.0\web\','C:\parentfolder8.0\web\'
$dstRoot = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
    
$params = @{
    Path      = LiteralPath      = $srcRoot |Where-Object { Test-Path -LiteralPath $_ -PathType Container }
    Filter    = 'views'
    Recurse   = $true
    Directory = $true
}

# All folders under `$srcRoot` with name 'views'
$viewsFolders = Get-ChildItem @params #this line is where the issue 
seems to start when Right-clicking -> Run with PowerShell
$params.LiteralPath = $viewsFolders.FullName
$params.Filter = 'graphics'
# All folders under `$viewsFolders` with name 'graphics'
$graphicsFolders = Get-ChildItem @params
$params.Remove('Directory')
$params.LiteralPath = $graphicsFolders.FullName
$params.File = $true # Only search for Files
$params.Force = $true
$params.Remove('Filter')

# All files under `$graphicsFolders`
foreach($file in Get-ChildItem @params)
{
    # Where the file name contains one of these filters
    foreach($filter in $filterLists)
    {
        if($file.Name -like $filter)
        {
            #$file
            Copy-Item -Path $($file.FullName) -Destination $dstRoot
            # if you want to stop at the first finding
            # add `break` here
        }
    }
}
```

Help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Where-Object` to filter the list of paths. Use `Test-Path` to test whether each exists and is a directory path:

```
$params = @{
    LiteralPath = $srcRoot |Where-Object { Test-Path -LiteralPath $_ -PathType Container }
    Filter      = 'views'
    Recurse     = $true
    Directory   = $true
}

# this will only attempt directory paths that actually exist now
$viewsFolders = Get-ChildItem @params
```

**Note**: Use of `LiteralPath` (instead of `Path`) above is intentional - using `Path` will cause PowerShell to attempt to expand wildcards like `?`, `*` or `[abc]`, whereas `-LiteralPath` only take exact file/folder names.

Comment: Mathias R. Jessen, thank you. I believe this does take us one step closer to the goal. The challenge seems to be that when running the PS1 script (Right-click -> Run with PowerShell), it will be now skip the errors when one of the directories do not exist but the code will not return any filenames that match the `$filterLists`. 

In the process, I'm trying to figure out how to troubleshoot PS1 extension files since running the actual PowerShell script in a terminal still seems to work.